# invalid realloc/realloc returns NULL

Tags: c, structure, realloc

In one function I used malloc :

```
void name1(struct stos* s)
{
   s = malloc (4 * sizeof (int));
}
```

And everything is ok. But later I used  realloc

```
void name2(struct stos* s)
{
   s->size = 2*(s->size);
   s = realloc (s, (s->size + 1) * sizeof (int));
}
```

and I get invalid free/delete/realloc in valgrind and realloc returns NULL.

Declaration  of Structure and rest of program is:

```
struct stos
{
   int top;
   int size;
   int stk[];
};

void name1(struct stos* s);
void name2(struct stos* s);    

int main()
{
   struct stos stosik;
   struct stos* s;
   s = &stosik;

   name1(s);

   //some operations on the array and int top here

   name2(s);
}
```

What did I do wrong here? I looked for what might have gone wrong for quite long, read quite a few articles about pointers, malloc/realloc etc. but with no result. I would be really grateful, if someone could help me.

Comment: Not sure why downvoting is really necessary here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is slightly subtle and caused by a combination of two things. Let's start here:

```
struct stos stosik;
struct stos* s;
s = &stosik;

name1(s);
```

First, you make `s` point to an a valid chunk of memory that is allocated on the stack (`stosik`) and then you call `name1` passing into `s`. Let's look at what `name1` looks like:

```
void name1(struct stos* s)
{
    s = malloc (4 * sizeof (int));
}
```

Hmm, we can see that `name1` takes in a pointer to a `struct stos` called `s`; inside that function, we are allocating some memory and making `s` point to it. This is a problem.

First of all, note that `s` already points to a valid chunk of memory. So using a `malloc` here is suspicious. It will cause a subtle bug that will actually hide the *real* bug in your program, which is bad. So, let's remove `stosik` completely:

```
int main()
    {
    struct stos* s = NULL;

    name1(s);

    if(s == NULL)
        return -1;
```

Now, if you run this program, you will see that after you call `name1` the variable `s` still points to `NULL`. What's happening here?

Well, we are changing the function's *LOCAL* copy of `s` (i.e. the `s` that exists only inside `name1`)... but the `s` in `main` isn't changed! Remember, that we are passing a pointer into `name1` but we are passing it *by value*.

To do what you seem to be trying to do you can do you would have to either pass a *pointer* to `s` into `name1` (that is, to pass a double pointer) or you should return the result of the `malloc` from `name1` as a return value. Let's look at each of these options:

### Passing `s` in via a double pointer

```
void name1(struct stos **s)
    {
    /* sanity check */
    if(s == NULL)
        return; 

    /* now, allocate enough space for four integers and make 
     * whatever s points to, point to that newly allocated
     * space.
     */
    *s = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
}
```

And calling it from `main` requires us to use the "address-of" operator:

```
struct stos *s = NULL;

/* we need to pass a pointer to s into name1, so get one. */
name1(&s);

/* malloc can fail; check the result! */
if(s == NULL) 
    return -1;
```

### Returning a pointer to the allocated memory from `name1`

```
struct stos *name1()
{
    return malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Calling this from `main` is slightly easier:

```
struct stos *s = name1();

/* malloc can fail; check the result! */
if(s == NULL)
    return -1;
```

Changing your code to what I show you here will fix this issue (but there may be others) but let me touch briefly upon something else:

### The other bug

The crash you encounterd crops up partially because of the problem we just covered; another issue is that inside `name2` you are calling `realloc`. The pointer you pass into `realloc` however, is **not** a pointer that you got back from `malloc` or `realloc`, which is what `realloc` expects. It points to `stosik` instead. So that code causes undefined behavior and after that *anything* can happen.

If you're lucky (it seems you were), it will just crash right then and there and if you're not... well, who knows what will happen?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer, now I see my mistakes. But after all, I decided I'll simply malloc/realloc memory only for an array which is a member of the structure (and then pointer to a pointer won't be needed, am I right?). Nevertheless, information from your answer are really useful.

Comment: I'd also note that if `realloc` fails inside the call to `name2`, you will lose the data in the memory that you had previously allocated. Better to save the result of realloc to a temporary variable and only assign it, when the result is not NULL

Answer (score 1):

1. if you want to dynamically allocate s in name1 you need it to be declared as `name1(struct stos** s)` and pass pointer to the pointer where the allocated memory should appear.
2. Your `main` allocates stosik staticaly, meaning you don't need to do any further dynamic allocation. Then when you try doing name1(statically allocated mem) it does … um, something. I don't know what, but certainly not what you expect.